# How can I send SOAP XML via Curl and PHP?

Tags: php, xml, soap, curl

This has been bugging me for days; I'm trying to send a SOAP post via Curl but I just keep getting a "couldn't connect to host" error, but, I really can't see how.

I have an ASP version which works fine with the same URL and data. I think it's just a PHP/Curl thing.

I currently have the following code (the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` data is a valid SOAP envelope string):

```
$soap_do = curl_init();
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            "https://xxx.yyy.com:517/zzz.asmx" );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );            
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     '<soap:Envelope>...</soap:Envelope>'); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: '.strlen('<soap:Envelope>...</soap:Envelope>') ));

if(curl_exec($soap_do) === false)
{                
    $err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($soap_do);
    curl_close($soap_do);
    return $err;
}
else
{
    curl_close($soap_do); 
    return 'Operation completed without any errors';
}
```

So any ideas why it just errors all the time?

The ASP version works fine! The code is:

```
Set xmlhttp = server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open "POST","https://xxx.yyy.com:517/zzz.asmx"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
xmlhttp.Send('<soap:Envelope>...</soap:Envelope>')
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Thanx a lot buddy, your code has worked for me.

Here is the code:

```
$soap_do = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            $url );   
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true ); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,    $post_string); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: '.strlen($post_string) )); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ":" . $password);

$result = curl_exec($soap_do);
$err = curl_error($soap_do);
```

Comment: I never got an answer which worked for me, and this was over 2 years ago now. People seem to find this answer useful, so I will mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Can someone help me out with vice versa of this ie turn curl request like above to a soapclient request?

Answer (score 11):

I had to use

```
$headers = array(             
    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"", 
    "Accept: text/xml", 
    "Cache-Control: no-cache", 
    "Pragma: no-cache", 
    "SOAPAction: \"run\"", 
    "Content-length: ".strlen($xml),
);
```

and

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Comment: Thanks Dom, I will give that a shot later on and let you know if it worked for me :)

Comment: +1 for SOAPAction: "run". That was the missing piece required by my soap server.

Answer (score 4):

For those finding this from Google, I ran into a similar problem, trying to interact with a .NET SOAP server from PHP, when the ASP method worked fine.

I used a packet sniffer to see what the ASP client was sending, exactly, and noticed it included cookies after the initial authentication request. So I enabled cookies in my cURL and it worked fine.

```
$cookiePath = tempnam('/tmp', 'cookie');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiePath);
```

Comment: After 2 days of working out why it wasnt working, this fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

This may be old, but this work for me. I originally had this function for an XML post and soap would not work until I change the `HTTPHEADER` to `text/xml` instead of `application/xml`:

```
function doXMLCurl($url,$postXML){
    $CURL = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postXML); 
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: text/xml','Content-Type: text/xml'));
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $xmlResponse = curl_exec($CURL); 

    return $xmlResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try and set the port number using CURLOPT_PORT as perhaps it's not liking it as part of the URL?

Comment: Already tried that one and it doesn't work :/ Thanks though for the idea

Answer (score 1):

Your also using the wrong Content-type, application/xml is the correct type. But that shouldn't make any difference to the cURL request.