# Using Google App Engine Proxy server to fetch RestFull webservices

Tags: google-app-engine

Hi im new to Google App Engine and I am trying to create a proxy server who can return RestFull data like xml and json responses from a remote server.

I want the webservices to answer requests from only a single IP adress and that's why i want to create a proxy server with Google App Engine. I tried that [solution](http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/188080/Google-Web-Toolkit-and-Web-Services-The-XML-Way)

But the remote calls to my Google App Server are Asynchronous so by the time the webservices answer to my Google App server, the Google App Server have already answer requests of my devices which have no data in it.

I have tried many solutions with python but i am not able to make them work.

If you have any questions, let me know

Thanks,

[image: Architecture]

Comment: What do you mean by "remote calls to my Google App Server are Asynchronous"? URLFetch in Python can be also used synchronously: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally It's seems there is no way to make synchronous remote calls from the client side on the server side of the Google Apps Engine. So I tryed curl on php and it works perfecly!

Here the StackOverflow post that helped me out [How can I send SOAP XML via Curl and PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006977/how-can-i-send-soap-xml-via-curl-and-php)