# any way to send the XML string to soap as request?

Tags: php, web-services, soap

any way to send the XML string to soap as request ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Header>
    <OGHeader transactionID="005435" timeStamp="2008-12-09T13:26:56.4056250-05:00" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/Core/">
      <Origin entityID="OWS" systemType="WEB" />
      <Destination entityID="WEST" systemType="ORS" />
    </OGHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <FetchCalendarRequest xmlns:a="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/Availability/" xmlns:hc="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/HotelCommon/" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/ows/5.1/Availability.wsdl">
      <HotelReference chainCode="AXA" hotelCode="AXAMUM" />
      <StayDateRange>
        <hc:StartDate>2013-10-01</hc:StartDate>
        <hc:EndDate>2013-10-10</hc:EndDate>
      </StayDateRange>
      <GuestCount>
        <hc:GuestCount ageQualifyingCode="ADULT" count="1" />
        <hc:GuestCount ageQualifyingCode="CHILD" count="0" />
      </GuestCount>
    </FetchCalendarRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CURL extension or any other HTTP Request library in PHP to send XML to a SOAP Service.

See this the comments on this article for some examples:
[How can I send SOAP XML via Curl and PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006977/how-can-i-send-soap-xml-via-curl-and-php)

You should realy use a real SOAP call from inside PHP as it will be much more convenient. If you can...